# recv function fails when used twice

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming

Hello all I have been working on a Server that receives the two address from a simple client and then prints them out using Asynchronous Sockets and the WINAPI, So far I have set up the window and have been able to accept a connection but when I try to send two messages to the Server it only receives one message and the second one fails. Here is the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hEdit = NULL;
    int len = sizeof(Server);
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:


        hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);

        break;
    case 1111:

        if (LOWORD(lParam) == FD_ACCEPT)
        {

            socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
            socket = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &len);


            print_line(hwnd, "IT WAS ACCEPTED!!!!!!!!\r\n");
        }
        if (LOWORD(lParam) == FD_CLOSE)
        {
            print_line(hwnd, "Client left the server!\r\n");

        }
        if (LOWORD(lParam) == FD_READ)
        {
            char NICK[4096] = { 0 };
            char IP[4096] = { 0 };
            ZeroMemory(NICK, strlen(NICK));
            ZeroMemory(IP, strlen(IP));
            if (recv(socket, IP, sizeof(IP), NULL) == INVALID_SOCKET)//get the IP address
            {
                print_line(hwnd, "Failed to recieve IP Address from socket!");
                print_line(hwnd, "\r\n");
            }
            if (recv(socket, NICK, sizeof(NICK), NULL) == INVALID_SOCKET)//get the Nickname
            {
                print_line(hwnd, "Failed to recieve nickname from socket!");
                print_line(hwnd, "\r\n");
            }
            //prints the Username and IP address to the window screen 
            print_line(hwnd, "Username: ");
            print_line(hwnd, NICK);
            print_line(hwnd, "\r\n");
            print_line(hwnd, "IP Address: ");
            print_line(hwnd, IP);
            print_line(hwnd, "\r\n");

        }
        break;
    default:



        HWND hEdit;
        RECT rcClient;

        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);

        hEdit = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT);
        SetWindowPos(hEdit, NULL, 0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER);


        return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));

    }
}
```

Comment: check the error before the second call and post the result

Comment: @MarcoA. You mean the first recv function call? If that is what you mean I already checked that and There is no error it prints the IP address

Comment: sorry, I meant: check the error after the second call so you can see what's wrong in a better detail

Comment: @MarcoA. How would I check it haven't I already checked that there is an error and that the buffer for the message is empty by trying to print it out? Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question I am just having a little trouble understanding what you mean by "check the error after the second call".

Comment: no problem, I meant to use [WSAGetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the error code after the failure

Comment: @MarcoA. The error code was 0 but isn't WSA part of the window so the socket failing to receive a message wouldn't send that to the window even when using WSAAsyncSelect at least I don't think so

Comment: Documentation says " If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero.", it might be it

Comment: @MarcoA. I use my own client and it didn't close when it sent the message and was able to send more but it won't get the messages with two receive functions at a time and that is the only way I can  think of to send the IP address and username of the client

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you intend on leaking that initial socket handle? You allocate a socket via `socket`, then immediately throw it into the ether and overwrite it irrecoverably via the followup `accept`. Even if `accept` fails (which you never check), you orphan that initial `socket()` result into no-mans land permanently. Sooner or later, you're going to run out of descriptors.

Comment: Creating a new socket and then accepting a socket into the same variable is pointless and a socket leak. Remove the first line of those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are using `WSAAsyncSelect()`, but you did not show the code that creates the listening socket or registers the message handler for it.

You should not use magic numbers in your code.  1111 is `WM_USER+87`, so you should assign that to a constant so it is easier to read, eg: `const UINT WM_SOCKETMSG = WM_USER + 87;`, then use that name in your `case` statement, eg: `case WM_SOCKETMSG:`.

Your socket message handler is calling `socket()` right before calling `accept()`.  `accept()` allocates and returns a new socket.  So you are leaking a socket every time an `FD_ACCEPT` notification is received.  And if multiple clients happen to connect, you are losing track of older sockets since you are using a single variable to keep track of them all.

You are not taking into account that TCP is a byte stream, `recv()` may return fewer bytes than you asked for.  It returns whatever data is currently available, not exceeding the size of the buffer you give it.  You are using an asynchronous socket, but you wrote your reading code as if you were using a synchronous socket instead (and even then, the logic you showed would fail at times).  If there is no data currently available, `recv()` will fail with an `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error, which you are not handling.  Whenever new data arrives, you need to read it into a rolling buffer, and then pull out only completed data from that buffer as needed, leaving incomplete data in the buffer so it can be completed by subsequent reads.

You need to design a protocol to control the flow of your data, you can't just throw arbitrary data around.  I seriously doubt you want 4KB usernames and waste ~3KB on IP addresses.  You need to delimit the values being transmitted, not only to reduce bandwidth usage but also to reduce memory needed to hold them.  For something simple like what you have shown, you could delimit the values with a LF character.  You can then look for that character when processing your rolling buffer.

And lastly, you are not handing errors at all.  You need to do so.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<SOCKET, std::string> ClientBuffers;
typedef std::map<SOCKET, std::string>::iterator BufferIterator; 

const UINT WM_SOCKETMSG = WM_USER + 87;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    switch (msg)
    {
        ...
        case WM_SOCKETMSG:
        {
            SOCKET socket = (SOCKET) wParam;
            int event = WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam);
            int error = WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam);

            switch (event)
            {
                case FD_ACCEPT:
                {
                    if (error == 0)
                    {
                        sockaddr_in clientaddr = {0};
                        int len = sizeof(clientaddr);

                        if (accept(socket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientaddr, &len) != INVALID_SOCKET)
                        {
                            print_line(hwnd, "A client connected to the server!\r\n");
                            break;
                        }

                        error = WSAGetLastError();
                    }

                    print_line(hwnd, "Error accepting a client!\r\n");
                    // handle the error on the reported socket as needed...

                    break;
                }

                case FD_CLOSE:
                {
                    if (error == 0)
                        print_line(hwnd, "A client left the server!\r\n");
                    else
                        print_line(hwnd, "A client connection was lost unexpectedly!\r\n");

                    BufferIterator i = ClientBuffers.find(socket);
                    if (i != ClientBuffers.end())
                        ClientBuffers.erase(i);

                    break;
                }

                case FD_READ:
                {
                    char buf[1024];

                    int numRead = recv(socket, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL);
                    if (numRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                        {
                            print_line(hwnd, "Failed to read from a client!\r\n");
                            // handle the error on the reported socket as needed...
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    if (numRead == 0)
                        break;

                    std::string &buffer = ClientBuffers[socket];
                    buffer += std::string(buf, numRead);

                    std::string::size_type idx1 = buffer.find('\n');
                    if (idx1 == std::string::npos)
                        break; // wait for more data

                    std::string::size_type idx2 = buffer.find('\n', idx1+1);
                    if (idx2 == std::string::npos)
                        break; // wait for more data

                    std::string IP = buffer.substr(0, idx1);
                    std::string NICK = buffer.substr(idx1+1, idx2-idx1-1);
                    buffer.erase(0, idx2+1);

                    //prints the Username and IP address to the window screen 
                    print_line(hwnd, "Username: ");
                    print_line(hwnd, NICK.c_str());
                    print_line(hwnd, "\r\n");
                    print_line(hwnd, "IP Address: ");
                    print_line(hwnd, IP.c_str());
                    print_line(hwnd, "\r\n");

                    break;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```